# Clojure-like way to have a data structure in a loop

Tags: clojure

I find it kinda hard to wrap my head around this. Say, in Python, if I want to have a list that I modify in a loop based on user input, I'd have something like this:

```
def do_something():
    x = []
    while(true):
        input = raw_input('> ')
        x.append(input)
        print('You have inputted:')
        for entry in x:
            print(entry)
```

I'm really not sure what's the most Clojure-like way to do something similar. So far I have something like this:

```
(defn -main
  [arg]
    (print "> ")
    (flush)
    (let [input (read-string (read-line))]
      ; Append a vector?
      (println "You have inputted:")
      ; Print the contents of vector?
      (recur <the vector?>)))
```

Basically, I append the vector and give the vector as argument for the next recursion loop. Is this the correct way of doing this? I'm not even sure how I would do that, but that's how I would do it. Where would I "store" the vector? Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing in python is that you are mutating vector x. This is not the standard way of doing things in clojure. Data structures in clojure are immutable by default. Therefore you have to create new vector every time and pass it to the next iteration.

```
(defn -main
  [arg]    
  (loop [vec []]
       (let [input (read-string (read-line))]
         (let [next-vec (conj vec input)]
           (println (str "You have inputted:" next-vec))
           (recur next-vec)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it works:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:use tupelo.core))

(defn loopy []
;        "var"   "init val"
  (loop [ idx      0
          result   "" ]
    (if (< idx 5)
      (recur (inc idx)              ; next value of idx
             (str result " " idx))  ; next value of result
      result)))
(spyx (loopy))


(defn -main [] )
```

and the output:

```
> lein run
(loopy) => " 0 1 2 3 4"
```

So the `loop` expression defines the loop "variables" and their initial values.  The `recur` expression sets up the values of each variable for the next iteration of the loop.

Since you are accumulating user input, you probably want to use a string instead of a vector.  Or, you could change it like this:

```
(defn loopy []
;      "var"   "init val"
  (loop [idx      0
         result   [] ]
    (if (< idx 5)
      (recur (inc   idx)             ; next value of idx
             (glue  result [idx] ))  ; next value of result
      result)))
(spyx (loopy))


> lein run (loopy) => [0 1 2 3 4]
```

to accumulate items into a vector. Note that you could also use this expression in the `recur` expression instead of `glue`:

```
(append result idx)
```

where the functions `append`, `glue`, and `spyx` are all [found in the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).   Enjoy!